# Datatable responsive and select extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement a `Datatable` to my products table. Also I want to be responsive and have the select extension(checkbox to each column).

I have implemented both but when the window is resized to small and the responsive table transforms in list, the checkbox vanish.

[image]

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jrntLad4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your column definitions, you aren't including the checkbox column in the priority list:

`{ responsivePriority: 1, targets: [2, -2, -3] },`

Changing it to:

`{ responsivePriority: 1, targets: [1, 2, -2, -3] },`

Keeps the checkbox visible

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jrntLad4/1/

Comment: Thank you. But I see another bug with responsivePriority.